# Древнерусский облик слов

Tags: этимология

Какой древнерусский облик слов подогнать – подгоню, борец – борцы, огонь – огни?  Что за происхождение беглых гласных в разных морфемах?

Answer (score 2):

Беглые гласные - это гласные ***о*** и ***е*** современного русского языка, чередующиеся с нулем звука при формообразовании и словообразовании.

Примеры. Сон/сна. День/дня. Огонь/огня.

> Беглые гласные объясняются тем, что в древнерусском языке на их месте
>   были не (о) и (е), а редуцированные, так называемые глухие (ъ) и (ь),
>   которые в известный период развития языка в сильной позиции
>   становились соответственно (о) и (е), а в слабой — исчезали: сънъ >
>   сон, а съна > сна.

Срисовано [отсель](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/105).

> Беглые гласные могут быть в корне (зову - звать, ров - рвы, беру -
>   брать, лев - льва, лён - льна), в приставке (собрать - сбор, подогнуть
>   - подгибать, надорвать - надрыв, отозваться - отзыв), в суффиксе (подарок - подарки, овражек - овражка, прекрасен - прекрасны).

[Отсель](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:oxRW3X50sIQJ:https://otvet.mail.ru/question/64680151%20&cd=2&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru) (там же и другие примеры с объяснениями).

***[Редуцированные гласные](http://les.academic.ru/954/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)*** - это сверхкраткие гласные среднего подъёма непереднего и переднего образования, унаследованные древними славянскими языками из праславянского (например, праслав. *sъnъ ‘сон’, *dьnь ‘день’). По традиции обозначаются кириллическими буквами «ъ» и «ь».

> В праславянском языке Р. г. возникли из индоевропейских ŭ и ĭ кратких
>   и отличались признаком сверхкраткости от долгих и кратких гласных.
>   Выступая как самостоятельные фонемы, Р. г. могли быть как под
>   ударением, так и в безударных слогах, но в любой позиции они звучали
>   короче и слабее остальных гласных. В положении перед j гласные «ъ» и
>   «ь» выступали в позиционных вариантах ы̌ («ы редуцированный») и и̌ («и
>   редуцированный»), например в древнерусских прилагательных красьны̌и̯,
>   сини̌и̯ (из krasьnъ + jъ, sinь + jъ).
>
> В истории всех славянских языков Р. г. были утрачены (так называемое
>   падение редуцированных). Под утратой Р. г., происходившей
>   неодновременно, понимается как их исчезновение, так и их изменение в
>   гласные полного образования — разные в разных славянских языках.
>   Падение Р. г. относится к 10 — 1‑й половине 13 века. Различная судьба
>   «ъ» и «ь» зависела от сильного или слабого их положения в словоформах:
>   сильным положением «ъ» и «ь» была позиция под ударением и перед слогом
>   со слабым редуцированным (например, pь̳́strуjь; bь̭rь̳vь̭no), слабым —
>   на конце слова (например, dьnь̭, sъnъ̭), перед слогом с гласным
>   полного образования или с сильным редуцированным (например, dь̭ni,
>   tь̭mь̳nъ̭). В слабых позициях Р. г. исчезли во всех славянских языках,
>   в сильных результаты их изменения оказались различными. В
>   древнерусском языке «ъ» → «о», «ь» → «е»...

Изобразить искомые слова не сумею (см.tь̭mь̳nъ̭ - темень? темно? а также pь̳́strуjь, bь̭rь̳vь̭no - пестрый, бревно?)...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот что это такое мне переводчик выдал? на-гора?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Подробно о [***падении редуцированных в древнерусском языке***](http://koi.tspu.ru/koi_books/kurysheva2/prvdy.htm)